# How do i merge this objects for form a new one of same kind?

Tags: javascript

I have two objects that say

```
let obj = {
    0: {
        "name": "Sasha",
        "age": 20
    }
    1: {
        "name": "Martha",
        "age": 30
    }
}
let obj2 = {
    0: {
        "name": "Stones",
        "age": 89
    }
}
```

Now I want the new object to be something like

```
new_obj = {
    0: {
        " name": "Sasha",
        "age": 20
    }
    1: {
        " name": "Martha",
        "age": 30
    }
    2: {
        " name": "Stones ",
        " age": 89
    }
}
```

I tried Using the spread operator or object.assign()
I.e

```js
const new_obj = {
    ...obj,
    ...obj2
} //doesn't give me what I want


const new_obj = Object.assign({}, obj, obj2) //doesn't give me what I want
```

How can I achieve that using any of the two methods if possible? Thanks for your usual help!!!

Comment: Consider using an array instead of an object with numeric keys. The two approaches you use cannot give the output you want.

Comment: Is `obj2` append with `obj1`?

Comment: User arrays instead of using objects with incremental numerical indices.

Comment: Use array instead of object with numerical indices, you can serialize and stringify the array just like an object and make use of all the Array.prototype methods. In the end of the day the array has similar behavior to your object with numerical indices but supports a whole lot of usecases. For exaple the usecase of apending a new object of the same kind with Array.push(object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append `obj2` to `obj` and reassign the key value of it,then you can use array iteration to do it

```js
let obj = {
    0: {
        "name": "Sasha",
        "age": 20
    },
    1: {
        "name": "Martha",
        "age": 30
    }
}
let obj2 = {
    0: {
        "name": "Stones",
        "age": 89
    }
}

let k1Len = Object.keys(obj).length
let k2s = Object.keys(obj2)

k2s.forEach(k2 => {
  obj[k1Len++] = obj2[k2]
})

console.log(obj)
```